# Matlab: What's 'label image'?

Tags: image, matlab, label

I don't understand the term/noun 'label image' in Matlab, and what's the normal usage of it? Details would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the label image or label matrix produced by functions such as `bwlabel`, or `bwconncomp` and `labelmatrix`.

The label matrix takes each connected component, that is each separate region of ON pixels, in a binary image and assigns it a unique integer "label."

For example, the binary image given by this matrix:

```
1 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

Would become this label matrix:

```
1 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 2 2 2
0 0 0 0 2 2 2
```

These are very useful functions for dealing with individual regions in binary images.  I often use patterns like:

```
labels = bwlabel(binaryImage);
for i=1:max(max(labels))
    regionMask = labels == i;
    %# do something with regionMask
end
```

or

```
bwcc = bwconncomp(binaryImage);
bwprops = regionprops(bwcc);
for i=length(bwprops)
    regionMask = imcrop(binaryImage,bwprops(i).BoundingBox);
    %# do something with regionMask
end
```